# Correct usage of the word flaky

Tags: word-usage, american-english

> My internet connection is flaky

Could this line be used when the internet is not working properly and say during a zoom call?
As per dictionary meaning what I understand is that I can use it for the following reasons:

1. I see the signal is there but still websites are not opening or are slow.
   (Indicating something weird)
2. Signal is improving and then becoming low.

But if the signal is low all the time. Is it correct to say My internet connection is flaky?

Comment: You could say that but it is not an accurate way to describe your connection.  You have a **weak** signal.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [Merriam-Webster’s definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flaky), this usage of ***flaky*** matches definition 2 of entry 2 - “not reliable in performance or behavior: UNDEPENDABLE”, and is quite commonly used, though most definitiely colloquial. In this usage, the *reason* for the unreliability is not specified, and thus if it is unreliable, whatever the reason, one can correctly call it ***flaky***.

Comment: I would be inclined to say that the performance of something was flaky if it was good sometimes but could be suddenly bad without warning or pattern.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - that's "undependable", almost by definition, no?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The question seems to understand that meaning, and asks 'But if the signal is low all the time. Is it correct to say My internet connection is flaky?', which is what my comment above addresses.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - If the signal is "low" all the time, such that the user/querent can't reliably visit sites he wants to, or such that streaming is intermittent and poor, then 'flaky', in the sense of 'unreliable' still applies.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Your definition of the word reliable may be an issue.  Reliable means *can be depended on*.  If your internet is *always* slow, then you can *rely* on it being slow.  It may be true that you cannot rely on a fast connection but you can rely on a slow one -- every single time you use it.  Things that you can rely on are not unreliable.